# Max limit on number of RDDs in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Spark and is currently learning related concepts. One basic question I have is what is the limit on number of RDDs in  Spark ?

Comment: Well, memory and disk space can limit how many RDDs you process in parallel, but other than that you can (AFAIK) have as many RDDs as you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to my knowledge, there is no limit on number of RDDs in Spark.

Only limitation is with memory and disk swap space Spark can expand/use.

I have been running spark over data of 40 tb in production, and yet to reach any kind of limit.